# Remove the limit on the number of characters that can be entered into a Win32 Edit control

Tags: c++, winapi, editcontrol, character-limit

I've searched everywhere and it seems I can't find a solution to this problem..

My problem isn't limiting the amount of characters that can be entered into an edit control, my problem is I am limited by the size of the edit control. I want to be able to type past the size of the edit control.

I've tried extending the character limit to a high number with SendMessage and sending EM_LIMITTEXT, but that only seems to work if I want to limit it even more.

Here's an image example of my problem:

[image: My problem]

I use CreateWindowEx to create the edit control, but there doesn't seem to be an extended window style OR an edit control style that achieves what I want.

Comment: Set the style `ES_AUTOHSCROLL`.  Source https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775464(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The style you're looking for is `ES_AUTOHSCROLL`. Without this style, input cannot go past the length of the edit control. With this style, text is automatically scrolled to the right by 10 characters when the input reaches the end of the control.

You may also be interested in `ES_MULTILINE`, which does exactly what it says. The default (without this style) is a single-line edit control.

All of the available styles are documented [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775464.aspx).  These are just regular window styles, not extended ones.

Also, I am pretty sure that you cannot change these styles at runtime, after the control has been created. Therefore, make sure that they are specified when you call `CreateWindowEx`, or in your resource file if the control lives on a dialog.

Comment: Thank you, ES_AUTOHSCROLL seemed to work for this. When I read the documentation on it, it didn't seem to be what I wanted but I guess it is.

Comment: This worked for me. In the resources file, the style was added to the edit control itself, not its containing dialog.